# scanf with %s returns only first character of the string

Tags: c

This is my function in my main

```
int get_name(void){
  char name;
  printf("Please enter the student name: ");
  scanf("%s", &name);

  return name;
}
```

I initialize my struct which is

```
typedef struct{
  char name[MAXSTRING];
  int id;
}student;
```

by doing

```
    name = get_name();

    number= get_id();

    student s1 = {.name=name , .id=number};

    printf("id is %d\n",s1.id);

    printf("name is %s\n", s1.name);
```

But what i get as a return is the first character of the string i enter.
MAXSTRING is defined in my student.h as

```
#define MAXSTRING 20
```

I am pretty sure i have to modify my name variable in some way but i tried a lot of things and nothng worked.
Also is it better to use fgets in this scenario?

Comment: `name` is a single `char`...

Comment: Also, you return an `int` when you want a string?

Comment: use `char name[20];` then `scanf("%19s", name);` but then you cannot return the local buffer... good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to provide a char *array*, not a pointer on a `char`. Then you cannot return the local array to the outer scope, so I'd suggest that you allocate the buffer:

```
char *get_name(void){
  char *name = malloc(100);
  printf("Please enter the student name: ");
  scanf("%99s", name);  // 99+1 limit avoids buffer overflow

  return name;
}
```

or a variant to allocate exactly the good number of bytes, using the *almost* standard `strdup` string function:

```
char *get_name(void){
  char name[100];
  printf("Please enter the student name: ");
  scanf("%99s", name);

  return strdup(name);
}
```

Your struct should then hold a pointer instead of a buffer:

```
typedef struct{
  char *name;
  int id;
}student;
```

you need to `free` it when not used anymore

Comment: while i call it like this

`name=get_name();`

when i run it and enter a name like chris i get a result of α

Are my pointers out of place?

Comment: `printf("%s\n",name);` right after that `get_name()` call should work. If you free the buffer in the meanwhile, it can break ...

Comment: `printf ` gives the desired result but then when i do 

`student s1 = {stname};` i still get α. Maybe because my struct is `char name[MAXSTRING];`

Comment: yes, my answer suggests that you change your struct member to `char *name` (else the pointer data is probably copied instead of the pointer itself... weird :))

Comment: Changed it to `char *name[MAXSTRING];` and now i just get more weird letters, akin to a string but deformed

Comment: It worked perfectly now. Just curious, is it possible to implement it in such a way that i get to keep my MAXSTRING declaration?

Comment: yes, get the name, copy the string using `strcpy`, free the name. Or pass the struct field as a parameter of the function as a pointer

Answer (score 1):

Jean-François Fabre's answer is so adequate. Alternatively, [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c) keyword can be used. However, `scanf()`'s usage like is not recommended. You should limit the input size, `scanf("%99s", name);`, to prevent [buffer overflow attacks](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/coen152_05/Lectures/BufferOverflow.html).

```
char* get_name(void){
  static char name[100];
  printf("Please enter the student name: ");
  scanf("%99s", name);

  return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `get_name()` function `name` is declared as of `char` type not as *char array*.

```
char name;
scanf("%s", &name);
```

Instead declare `name` as char array of some size. for.e.g

```
char name[20];
scanf("%s", name); /* &  is not needed as name itself address */
```

But then returning local array like `return name;` would cause undefined behavior. Better create the dynamic array & return it.

Or declare `name` as pointer variable & allocate memory for it & then scan the data from user.

```
char *name = malloc(SIZE); /* define the size */
scanf("%s",name); 
return name; /*returning dynamic array, catch with another pointer in calling function & free it once done */
```

Once you done with dynamic memory don't forget to free it by calling `free(name)`.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a character, not a string.

You need to change the declaration to `char name[MAXSTRING]` or `char *name = malloc(MAXSTRING)`. However, since you are returning `name`, you should return the address of something allocated on the heap instead of the stack. As a consequence, you should probably use the `malloc`.

Then, you won't have to give the address of `name`: `scanf("%s", name)` or even `scanf("%20s", name)` if you want to protect your code against a buffer overflow.

Finally, instead of returning a string, you could also take the name as an argument:

```
void get_name(char *name) {
    printf("Please enter the student name: ");
    scanf("%d", name);
}
```

and call it that way:

```
student s1;
get_name(s1.name);
```

That way, you don't need to allocate and free some memory.